# Symfony CollectionType: this value is not valid (TransformationFailedException)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm facing a weird error **when customizing the form theme**
"This value is not valid" when submitting a form containing a collection.

When the form is not customized, it's working as excepted.
When it's working, the name of an entry is 
`example[expOnlines][0][name]`
when it's not it looks like `example[expOnlines][0]`

```
{% block _cv_expOnlines_widget %}
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
        {{ block('collection_add_button') }}
    </div>

    <div class="c-form__field col-md-12">
        {{ block('collection_widget') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block _cv_expOnlines_entry_row %}
    <div class="py-3 row" {{ block('row_container_attributes') }}>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            {{ block('collection_delete_button') }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[PHP side](https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/970159884261d360f1ece688f40523dc) (but the bug is not there, because it only happens when overriding the `form_theme`)

[image]

This errors appears on all my `CollectionType` on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was missing an important point,

It's **not** a `form_widget_simple` block. Instead I should do :
`{{ block('form_widget') }}`

That fixed the problem.

Comment: That makes sense! If the collection was of just text inputs, you'd not have seen this error due to your customization, right? But the collection item had more than 1 field?

Comment: No, it has exactly 1 field, but CollectionType has a compound => true